# Написання особливо означених термінів з великої літери

Tags: терміни, правопис, велика-мала-літера

У деяких ділових документах використовують capitalized terms – терміни, написані з великої літери. Так, на сайті Антимонопольного комітету України (далі – Комітет) я знайшов ось такі визначення:

https://amcu.gov.ua/storage/app/uploads/public/5f8/43e/d5f/5f843ed5f2be6671871301.pdf

> Заявник у Заяві 1 зазначив, що 30.04.2019 переглянув **рекламний відеоролик** послуги «Ідеальний роумінг» Товариства (**далі – Рекламний ролик**), що активно транслюється на телебаченні та в мережі Інтернет, у якому йдеться про можливість здійснення дзвінків у роумінгу за тарифом 1 грн за 1 хвилину і користування Інтернетом за тарифом 0,1 грн за 1 Мб.
> Заявник 1 зазначає, що після перегляду **Рекламного ролика** вирішив ознайомитись з умовами послуги «Ідеальний роумінг», проте умови послуги не розміщені у відкритому доступі на офіційній сторінці сайту Товариства, попри те, що в **Рекламному ролику** повідомляється, що умови послуги зазначені на сайті Товариства.

https://amcu.gov.ua/storage/app/sites/1/imported_content/5d690f00f2752.pdf

> Відповідач у відповіді на вимогу Комітету від 07.09.2017 № 127-26/09-9683 повідомив, що рекламу власних послуг із використанням Тверджень у друкованих рекламних матеріалах, зовнішній рекламі, відеороликах та на власному сайті здійснював на основі результатів **дослідження** «Аналіз даних 3G покриття операторів мобільного зв'язку України», проведеного компанією «InMind» (далі − **Дослідження**). Результати **Дослідження** Товариство надало Комітету.

Також написання термінів з великої літери використовується у [**листах Державної податкової служби України**](https://www.profiwins.com.ua/uk/letters-and-orders/dpsu.html).

Як бачимо, один раз термін написаний з малої літери, при цьому йому дається деяке спеціальне позначення, і в подальшому цей термін пишеться з великої літери. Наскільки я знаю, відповідної норми Правопису не існує.
Теоретично можна за цією логікою розробити, наприклад, таке речення:

> Я можу зауважити, що виділення термінів і написання їх з великої літери іноді використовують в **офіційно-діловому** (далі — **Офіційно-діловий стиль**) і рідко в **публіцистичному стилі** (далі — **Публіцистичний стиль**), з таким же успіхом можна дістатися **художнього стилю** (далі — **Художній стиль**).

Чи можна на практиці, наприклад при написанні курсової чи кваліфікаційної роботи, виділяти таким чином терміни, при цьому надалі пишучи їх з великої літери?

Answer (score 4):

Насправдï тут зазначені вирази є не просто термінами, а *скороченими найменуваннями*<sup>1</sup>, тобто:

- *Рекламний ролик* від *рекламний відеоролик послуги «Ідеальний роумінг» Товариства*,
- *Дослідження* від *дослідження «Аналіз даних 3G покриття операторів мобільного звʼязку України», проведеного компанією «InMind»*.

Причому вже помітно, же перший приклад має скорочення як *Товариство*. А другий: *Відповідач, Комітет, Твердження, Товариство*. Таке зроблено щонайменше з декількох причин:

- Офіційно-дїловий стиль не заохочуює синомії чи розбіжність понятть, коли художнїй — цїлком.
- Для спрощення сприйняття, таким часто послуговується і згаданий тут публіцистичний, і нп. науковий стиль, щоправда переважно на гинший манїр. Художнїй при тім не обовʼязково мусе бути легкоспийнятним.
- Велика буква тут, аби розрізнити від загальних назв: *рекламний рокик* може будь-який, а *Рекламий рокик* — вже власна назва. А художнїй покладається на мети чи бажаннь творця, тому якщо на теє воля, то можна писати хоч будь-яке слово з великої.

Отже. Чи може художнїй стиль мати такого? Так, за останїм пунтком, а також, як вже влучно сказано на тій ж Віцї:

> Художній стиль мовлення можна розглядати як узагальнення й поєднання *всіх стилів*, оскільки письменники органічно вводять ті чи ті складники стилів до творів, надаючи їм більшої переконливості та правдивості в зображенні подій.

Але треба розуміти, же такий вжив буде вирізняти ся від звичного художнього, де зазвичай передають тонкостї самими словами (тою ж синомією), а не типоґрафією. Також в книгах зазвичай підкреслюють слово чи вирази курсивним чи жирним шрифтом.

---

Виноски

1. Було б непогано відзнайти правила щодо таких. А такий термін узяв з [Про затвердження Вимог щодо написання найменування юридичної особи або її відокремленого підрозділу](https://minjust.gov.ua/m/str_39629) від Мінʼюста.

Comment: з таким же успіхом можна використати скорочені найменування в такому контексті: 
У  сучасній світовій лінгвістичній науці розмовна лексика (далі  – Розмовна лексика) представлена повною мірою, починаючи з фамільярно-просторічної і закінчуючи  табуйованою лексикою. Незважаючи на неоднозначне до неї ставлення, Розмовна  лексика становить досить значну і невіддільну частину словникового складу сучасної мови. Актуальність теми дослідження зумовлена необхідністю більш повного визначення та всебічного вивчення проблеми передачі англомовної Розмовної лексики українською  мовою...

Comment: @Vlad26t Проблема в тім, же розмовна лексика вже є терміном від суч. лінґ. науки, тому приклад такий собі. Та і скорочують зазвичай до РЛ, що вже є вживаною практикою в лекціях.

Comment: Ще один приклад, котрий був би нормальнішим: Роботу над «Кайдашевою сім'єю» (далі – Повість, або Твір) І. Нечуй-Левицький закінчив у 1878 році. Наступного року Твір вийшов у львівському журналі «Правда», одразу ж у Львові здійснили окреме видання Повісті. Однак у Російській імперії цензура дуже довго не дозволяла публікацію. Тоді письменник підготував нову редакцію. Одержавши нарешті російський цензурний дозвіл, він опублікував її в Києві в 1887 році.

Comment: Це визначені основними положеннями документу терміни, такими, як от, наприклад, Закон України або Комерційна Угода, або Правила Користування, що використовуються в межах цих документів.

Comment: @RomanMikhol Чи можна писати з великої літери визначені основними положеннями художнього розповідного твору терміни, якщо я жодного разу не зустрічав цього явища саме в Художньому Стилі?

Comment: @Vlad26t Художньому стилю притаманне використання великої кількості епітетів, метафор, гіпербол, порівнянь та синонімів, що збагачують мову і оживляють уяву читача. Офіційний стиль викладення навпаки мусить запобігати неоднозначності і різночитанню. Тому термінам на початку документу надають визначення і потім пишуть їх з великої літери, щоб відокремити від загальновживаних слів.

Comment: @RomanMikhol А що стосується наукового стилю, то до його функцій входить запобігання неоднозначності і різночитанню, чи я помиляюсь?

Comment: @Vlad26t Науковий стиль мовлення вітає і заохочує спільнота ukrainian.stackexchange.com! Обґрунтування  висновків і пояснення результатів досліджень простими словами з наведенням цитат та посиланнями на першоджерела.

Answer (score 1):

Загалом є така практика. Наприклад, я перекладав шашкову книгу з португальської, і вираз «Dama forçada» перекладав як «Одиначка».
Одинока ламка (далі — Одиначка).
А три дамки, як «Дамки». Якщо писати дамки з малої, то не зрозуміло, чи це стосується сторони гри, чи кількох шашок цієї сторони, бо Дамки — це саме суб'єкт (гравець, що грає білими чи чорними), а не об'єкт (шашкові фігури).