# Наскільки усталеним є вживання власних назв з маленької літери у випадку країни-агресора та її ватажків?

Tags: велика-мала-літера

Нещодавно в соцмережах поширилося таке явище, як використання назви терористичної банди-агресора і її ватажків з маленької літери: *московія, пітун, лавров, росія, бамбіть варонєж, гнати фашиста до москви*, тощо.

Цілком зрозуміла всенародна ненависть українців до терористичної шайки, яка влаштувала війну на знищення українського народу. Менше з тим, цікавить, в якій мірі усталеним є це явище з точки зору правил української мови.

У нас на сайті є декілька запитань на тему [велика-мала-літера](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%96%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0), але здебільшого вони стосуються правомірності написання саме з великої літери певних слів у певних випадках. Мені здається, що ці дописи не містять відповіді на моє запитання. Ось ці дописи, для контексту:

- [Написання особливо означених термінів з великої літери](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6670/)
- [Велика чи мала літера: (Д/д)ень (С/с)вятого Валентина, (Д/д)ень усіх закоханих?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/646/)
- [Чи правильно вживати "персеїди" з малої літери в значенні окремих метеороїдів і спалахів, які вони породжують у нічному небі?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6711/)

Comment: Забагато шани всяку мерзоту з Великої літери позначати. 
"Прислухайтесь, як океан співає —
Народ говорить. І любов, і гнів
У тому гомоні морськім. Немає
Мудріших, ніж народ, учителів;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Згадані туʼ запитання і во̂дпове̂дї справде̂ не роскривають причини написання, а лише приво̂д — зго̂дно правил. Через це радю звернути увагу на запитання [*Написання з великої літери заіменника «Ви»*](/q/361/585)». Там запитаннє хоть і стосувало ся лише слова *ви*, але там наведено і загальні слова.

Ось причина, як її формулює проф. **[Іван Ющук](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)** (нар. 1933), автор 30 новаторських підручників з української мови для середніх та вищих шкіл:

> <sub>Іван Ющук *(переписано)*</sub>
>
> *З великої букви пишуть ся слова, вжиті в шанобливому чи по̂днесено-переносному значеннї*.

Десь такої ж самої думки **[Олекса Синявський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)** (1887-1937), провідний діяч у нормуванні української літературної мови:

> <sub>Синявськиь *(переписано)*</sub>
>
> Це наьбо̂льш субєктівниь розряд вживання великої літери на письме̂, хоть деякі випадки і з цього розряду набули вже великого поширення, стаючи маьже обовязковими. Це велика літера з *пошани* і з *особливої уваги*. — [Норми української літературної мови](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/ortoepia) (1941)

Які висновки маємо з цього текста:

- Якщо прибрати велику букву, то прибираємо також *особливу увагу* і *пошану*,
- Субєктівне, але вже по сутї узусне, тобто поширене явище.
- Во̂д себе: во̂чьовидна причина про візуялну ро̂зницю тут не наведенo, бо не тиь вме̂ст, хоча теж може бути елементом для незваги, наприклад *роССкі*, де треба по̂дкреслити увагу на споро̂днено̂сть з *СС*.

---

<sup>20 вересня 2023 року</sup>

Фактічно, Наційональна комісія зо̂ стандарто̂в державної мови [погодила ся](//mova.gov.ua/news/napysannia-nazv-rosiiska-federatsiia) з таким вжитком.

> […], Національна комісія зі стандартів державної  мови на засіданні від 15.09.2023 (протокол № 83) обговорила це питання і з урахуванням офіційних листів від Інституту української мови НАН України (вх. № 1396/23 від 14.09.2023), Інституту мовознавства імені О. О. Потебні НАН України (вх № 1404/23 від 15.09.2023) повідомляє, що написання назв «російська федерація», «росія», «москва», «московія», «московське царство», «російська імперія»», «державна дума рф» тощо з малої букви можна не кваліфікувати як відхилення від норм української мови в текстах неофіційного характеру.

---

Дотичне.

То залежно во̂д особи, тобто причини щодо цього також можна списати на ле̂нь — прово̂дна култура мережи, де часто пишуть взагале̂ без великих букв, пунктуаціь та гинших правил.

Додаткове дʼуваги: [черга ро̂зних розмеро̂в букв](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_caps).

Comment: Дякую. я, з вашого дозволу, вніс правки з метою підкреслення вагомості авторів, бо bounty передбачає "is looking for an answer from a reputable source".

Answer (score 6):

Часткова власна відповідь, але я все ще очікую на те, що хтось зможе дати кращу відповідь, посилаючись на більш формальні правила української мови.

---

Історія почалася з того, що на початку березня автор шкільних підручників з української мови та літератури, доцент Київського університету імені Бориса Грінченка **Олександр Авраменко**, який також є розробником численних тестів до ЗНО з української мови, на національній освітній платформі «Всеосвіта» [розмістив допис](https://chesno.ck.ua/2022/03/16/znevazhlyva-gramatyka-vijny-vlasni-nazvy-ta-imena-agresora-pyshemo-z-maloyi-litery/) у стилі тестового завдання до ЗНО:

> «Урок 41. Минулого року я переїхав з Києва до Бучі. Я встиг полюбити це місто. Але мою любов зруйнувала росія. Памятайте про злочини «братського народу»…
> Орфографічну помилку допущено в написанні слова: 1) Києва 2) росія 3) памятайте».

Оскільки правильною, вочевидь, є відповідь (3), то пан Авраменко, таким чином, запропонував писати назву країни-агресора з маленької літери.

Згодом в ефірі загальнонаціонального телемарафону Олександр Авраменко пояснив:

> «Насправді правило таке є: прізвища людей та імена, які вживають зневажливо, пишуть з малої літери. І це правило давнє. Наприклад, *гітлери, путіни* ми можемо спокійно писати з малої літери, це відповідає вимогам чинного правопису. А щодо назви країни, цього немає в правописі, але за аналогією, зважаючи на ситуацію в країні, я вважаю, можна застосувати це правило і до неї».

Як [зазначає](https://mind.ua/news/20237194-avramenko-avtor-pidruchnikiv-i-zavdan-zno-rekomendue-pisati-rosiya-z-malenkoyi) психолог **Олена Каліман**, при сприйнятті тексту маленькі літери мають дещо інший психологічний ефект, ніж великі літери. Слово, написане з маленької літери, сприймається як щось просте і звичне, дрібне. Тоді як велика літера викликає більше уваги, тривоги, поваги. Зокрема, абревіатури мають досить сильний вплив на емоційне сприйняття. Зустрічалися навіть заклики не писати великими буквами абревіатури на зразок *СНІД, COVID*, щоб не викликати до них зайвої «поваги».

> Коли ми пишемо з маленької букви – ми ніби зменшуємо суб'єктивну значимість поняття, робимо його буденним, а іноді і зневажливим. Теперішня тенденція писати з малої літери слова, пов’язані з російською агресією, – це коктейль зневаги, супротиву та ворожості»

Ініціативу мовознавця підтримали й інші колеги. Так, редакторка **Ольга Васильєва** [розтлумачила](https://www.facebook.com/olha.vasylieva.litred/posts/322431989871695), що в українській мові існує троп (прийом виразності) **антономазія**, який ґрунтується на тому, що власне ім’я, найчастіше ім’я особи (історичного або літературного персонажа), яка вирізняється якоюсь характерною ознакою, стає прикметою цієї ознаки й пишеться з малої букви:

- *донжуан* — бабій;
- *ромео* — закоханий романтик;
- *гобсек* — скупа людина;
- *ейнштейн* — учень-відмінник, якого не розуміють однолітки;
- *ємєля / ванька* — пересічний росіянин;
- *гітлер / путін* — вбивця століття;
- *росія* — країна-терорист тощо.

Працює цей троп і у зворотний бік: з великої букви пишемо **апелятиви** типу *Безсмертний Кобзар* (про Тараса Шевченка), *Великий Каменяр* (про Івана Франка) і подібні. У негативному значенні — *Кобиляча Голова* (про лаврова), *Зливний Бачок* (про скабєєву), *Бункерний Щур* (про путіна), *Бензоколонка* (про росію) тощо».

Comment: Не певен, що варто пов'язувати антономазію і написання з малої літери задля вираження неповаги. Антономазію можуть застосовувати незалежно від того, добра людина/риса чи погана: робінзон, ментор, меценат. А явище написання з малої літери задля вираження неповаги безумовно існує, але це, мені здається, окрема річ.